# dynamically allocating an array of dynamically allocated strings in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm new to C and I'm having a problem with saving dynamically allocated strings in dynamically allocated array.
I tried to look at a simple example:

```
int*    p_array;

// call malloc to allocate that appropriate number of bytes for the array

p_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);      // allocate 3 ints


// use [] notation to access array buckets
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    p_array[i] = 1;
}
```

however, when I'm debugging it in visual studio it seems like I don't have an array with 3 slots, in p_array it shows me only {1} . the same problem happened to me with my actual code that I'm trying to write: in the actual code, I get from the user a polynomial in the running time, and need to put in an array each term of the polynomial in a different cell. I don't know the polynomial length so I need to allocate the array dynamically. in this example I wrote a constant string as the polynomial for your help.  the I'm trying to enter to the array the terms but as the other example, in the debugging I only see at the end the array {2x}

```
char[] polynom = "2x +5x^2 +8";
char* term;
char** polyTerms;
int i=0;
term = strtok(polynom, " ");
polyTerms = (char**)malloc(3* sizeof(polynom));


while (term != NULL)
{

    polyTerms[i] = (char *)calloc(strlen(term) + 1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(polyTerms[i], term);
    term = strtok(NULL, " ");

    i += 1;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: `char[] polynom = "2x +5x^2 +8";` --> `char polynom[] = "2x +5x^2 +8";`

Comment: When allocating the array of pointers you need to make sure you are allocating enough space. Replace `polyTerms = (char**)malloc(3* sizeof(polynom));` with `polyTerms = malloc(sizeof term * sizeof polynom);`

Answer (score 0):

First code snippet:

The debugger doesn't know how much you have allocated in `p_array` and therefore it doesn't display the size of the array and more than the first element. BTW `p_array` is not an array but just a pointer to `int`.

Second code snippet:

The code looks correct to me but it's:

```
char polynom[] = "2x +5x^2 +8";
```

and not

```
char[] polynom = "2x +5x^2 +8";
```

Answer (score 0):

When allocating the array of pointers you need to make sure you are allocating enough space.

`(char**)malloc(3* sizeof(polynom));`

Will most likely not allocate all the memory needed.

Use:

`polyTerms = malloc(sizeof term * sizeof polynom);`

Also, you may want to look into using [strdup()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc.aspx) in your code that allocates and copies into your array.

```
polyTerms[i] = (char *)calloc(strlen(term) + 1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(polyTerms[i], term);
```

Can become:

```
polyTerms[i] = _strdup(term); // VS2013 version of POSIX strdup()
```

Comment: An as mentioned by Michael, you need to declare your array correctly. `char polynom[] = "2x +5x^2 +8";`

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(char)` is always 1.